# Plesk 11 update makes domain not reachable with www

Tags: webserver, plesk, vhosts

hope someone can help me after my update to plesk 11.

I have 4 domains and 2 of them are not reachable after update to plesk 11.

Before all domains were reachable:

```
http://www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
```

now it only works with:

```
mydomain.com
```

If i go to www.mydomain.com there is a default page:
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: do you have `A, AAAA, CNAME` records for www.domain.com in dns? and what records do you have for www.domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

check with your cname record for domains www added and also check with your dns template